# Add a div to parent photo with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to add a parent div `<div id="lightbox"> my image </div>` if my `<a>` tag has specific class `.mystyle`

```
  <a class="mystyle" href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <img class="" src="">
  </a>
```

Should be changed to:

```
<div id="lightbox">
  <a class="mystyle" href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <img class="" src="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @omid, I think people may be confused about what your question is exactly.  Do you mind clarifying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code can help you

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('a.mystyle');
  for (var i =0; i <elems.length; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute("id", "lightbox");
    div.appendChild(elems[i]);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  } 
});
```

Alternatively if you want to use jquery and want to wrap as it is 
then use the `wrap` method of jQuery. 
https://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```
$( "a.mystyle" ).wrap( "<div id='lightbox'></div>" );
```

Comment: It does not change in the same section and is transferred to the before of the ‌</body>

Comment: Please tell me the section name, where do you want to append the code. I will edit accordingly. If the section ID is "section_id". then you can write `document.getElementById("section_id").appendChild(div)`

Comment: These images are inline the content of my blog post

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'lightbox';
var anchor = $('a.mystyle');
anchor.parentElement.appendChild(div);
div.appendChild(anchor);
```

Comment: not generate any div

Comment: But you question states that you need to wrap anchor in a div. <a></a> should be converted to <div><a></a></div>, so I guess question need a little bit edit.

Answer (score -1):

Just do:

```
$('a[class*="mystyle"]').parent().addClass('lightbox')
```

OR

```
$('a.mystyle').parent().addClass('lightbox')
```